# Can't move certain apps to my SD card

Tags: sd-card, internal-storage

I recently reset my phone to factory settings, because I didn't have enough space on my internal memory, and I wanted to start off anew.

When I started downloading apps onto my phone that I had before, I didn't have the option to move it to my SD card any longer, I can't move apps like "Viggle" or "Kik Messenger", which are from the App Store.

I run out of space easily on my internal memory, and it drives me nuts. Is there anything I can do to move my apps to my SD card or something? So I can have more space on my phone. I also still have the same SD card that was given to me with the phone which is 2 GB, and I still have a lot of space left over either way.

Comment: do you mean that you were able to move them before resetting or you didn't install them before that?

Comment: Have you tried App2SD? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd

Comment: [How to move apps from internal to external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Phones WITH SD card support, Android 6.0+ will ask you whether you want to use the SD Card as portable or internal storage. If you do not plan on moving the SD Card between devices, you can use it as internal storage. That will essentially increase your storage capacity. Mind you, if you ever remove the SD card after designating as "internal", some applications may stop working on your phone, and the card need to be formatted again to be used on different device.

Answer (score 0):

You can not move all application on SD card. Which operating system you are using. In marsh mellow go to setting / apps. Select your apps. You can find option move app to SD card.