# How to move apps from internal to external storage?

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd, lucky-patcher

I'm trying to move with Lucky Patcher (also with app2sd and Samsung stock app) some apps from internal to external storage, but everytime with every apps movable I got this message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: New installs into ASEC containers no longer supported
```

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0 and root.

Do you now why this happens? Maybe, Android 8.0 doesn't allow anymore this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native `app2sd` method - which placed encrypted `.asec` files in `.android_secure` folder on external SD card - was available only up to Android 5. For details see [Why root cannot access “.android_secure” directory on external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221485/218526)

Starting with Marshmallow, the native method of moving apps to external SD card works only if SD card is formatted as `Adoptable Storage` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8c61e39e042c31dd21567897c834c7c45fe7181b), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#732))</sup>:

> ASEC containers have been deprecated since MNC, which is when we
>   introduced the "adoptable storage" feature.  Adoptable storage is a
>   much better user experience, since we move both the APK and private
>   app data together as a single unit.

<sup>* MNC is *Macadamia Nut Cookie*; code name for Android Marshmallow (6.x).</sup>
And:

> new installs into ASEC containers are no longer supported; use adoptable storage instead.

[Adoptable Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable) is a Full Disk Encrypted SD card, completely managed by `vold`, not visible to user as external SD card. See [here](https://fossbytes.com/android-sd-card-internal-storage-adoptable-storage/) how it differs from traditional [Portable Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/traditional.html). You can format SD card as partially Adoptable and partially Portable too.

Like the pre-Marshmallow `app2sd` phenomenon <sup>([3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location))</sup>, apps only with `installLocation` set to `preferExternal` or `auto` in app's `manifest` are moveable:

> Apps can be placed on adopted storage media only when the developer has indicated support through the `android:installLocation` attribute.

For apps with install location `auto`, default install location (set using `pm set-install-location`) decides where app will be installed. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43522/218526) for details.

If you want to move all apps, use a third party solution like `Apps2SD` or `Link2SD`.

**PS:**
An even better approach is to move `/data/media` instead of apps. Create an extra partition on external SD card and `on post-fs-data` mount it to `/data/media` using an `init.d` script or Android's `init` service. Other bigger directories `/data/app` or `/data/data` can also be moved in the same way.

If you want to keep files encrypted on external SD card, this can be achieved through native methods `dm-crypt` (Android's `FDE`) for block device encryption, `ecryptfs` for stacked filesystem encryption, or third party solution like `EncFS` for stacked encryption. New native method of filesystem encryption `fscrypt` (Android's `FBE`) may also work, but I haven't tried. See details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216780/218526).

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Comment: Can you explain the ps part. I don’t have adoptable storage on Rooted android 5. Sdcard has a f2fs partition which is same as /data. Can I make symlink a folder to sdcard partition to /data ? It will be removed after reboot…so can I make it persistent from init script ?