# Is there a way to move apps to sd card if your phone doesnt support it?

Tags: sd-card, huawei, emui

In Huawei Phones moving apps to sd card isn't supported,there isn't an option to use sd card as internal storage too,is there anyway to bypass that and move apps to sd card without rooting android phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't move apps from internal to external storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200850/cant-move-apps-from-internal-to-external-storage)

Comment: @Irfan Latif I forgot to mention that in Huawei we don't have an option to use sd card as internal storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer on non-rooted devices is no. If the OS doesn't allow it, you will not be able to. If the device is rooted, then there are many (apps, scripts, etc) ways that will help you achieve it.

Comment: so the only possible way to do this is exploit in non-rooted devices right?

Comment: It means you will need to root your device.