# How to install apps to SD card with low internal storage - adoptable, app2sd, Xposed?

Tags: 9.0-pie, app2sd, adoptable-storage, xposed-framework

I’ve spent hours today trying to install an app on my 9.0 phone.

App size: ~1.5gb

Internal storage: 13/16gb.

SD card (formatted to adoptable): 4/64gb

I’ve read answers here explaining why it won’t work, others mentioning symlink or terminal commands, and others talking about link2sd and root options.

Basically I have a lot of outdated and incomplete answers from here, with no real verified recent solutions.

I thought this would be a simple search but I’m trying to get a conclusive answer before spending another day fiddling with my phone.

Too bad I can’t use my Stack Overflow rep for a bounty. Thank you fine people for your time.

(If anyone knows a definitive rooted and unrooted solution then hopefully this answer can help someone else looking for a 2020 response.)

Comment: all newly installed apps will go to adoptable-storage automatically

Comment: Adoptable Storage and Apps2SD/Link2SD are working solutions (at least up to Android 9) with their pros and cons. Not sure about Xposed. For details see [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526) and [How to move apps from internal to external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526). Make the question more specific if you find something missing or not working or if you have a specific requirement.

Comment: @alecxs the adoptable storage does not work. I am getting insufficient storage error with the prompt to delete. I’ve tried reformatting and ensured it was adoptable multiple times

Comment: @IrfanLatif the specific question would how to get the adoptable storage to work properly, since I cannot install any apps due to insufficient storage errors. I saw the answers you linked to earlier

Comment: That's answered in linked questions. Note `installLocation`. But I'm not sure if app is directly installed to SD card (or moved after installation) if `installLocation` is set to `preferExternal` or `auto`. I personally never used Adoptable Storage, except for testing.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I had read that answer earlier but it seems like I was just looking for something More clear like “use bind mounts, here is the terminal command” I’ll give it a go tomorrow

Comment: have you ever tested free up storage (moving DCIM to PC, uninstall updates or apps)? if you uninstall, then install, it is installed to adoptable-storage. bear in mind the reason for playstore not installing apps might not be related to actually storage