# How do I move apps to SD card on Android 7

Tags: applications, root-access, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I'm getting tired of deleting apps to install an app. Right now I need every app I got but also need to download another app. I got no more space left. I've searched high and low for a way to move my apps, completely, to SD card but to no avail. And I don't want to "link" them to SD. I want to "move" them to create space.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Android 7 | Rooted | Moto C Plus

Comment: See [How to move apps from internal to external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526) and [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Comment: @alecxs So does linking using Link2SD actually move the files and it's data, thus freeing up the space they were using in the internal storage?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the links! That's a tad bit too advanced. Can I get a little more guidance? Considering I'm using Android 7, which method would do the job without going the adoptable storage route?

Comment: Adoptable Storage is the easiest way to avoid manual setup (though personally I don't like it much and never used it). Everything else requires something advanced, and starts with rooting the device.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Like mention in op, my phone is already rooted. I'm not a complete noob so the advanced route shouldn't be that complicated. Could you point me in the right direction? I'd like to give it a shot. I don't want to do adoptable storage because I have bad experience with it.

Comment: @alecxs OK. What's the difference between that (Linking) and the method Irfan is talking about?

Comment: adoptable-storage is native app to sd method where android is aware of the location, while other methods are cheating

Comment: @alecxs I think IrfanLatif is talking about two methods...adoptable storage and something else. It's the something else I'm wondering about.

Comment: asec container was predecessor of adoptable-storage

Comment: There are numerous possibilities. Mount a partition or a directory from SD card to `/data/app` or `/data/data` or `/data/media`. Or bind mount specific app directories. SD card must be of app grade for a smooth experience. You can create `init` services to automatically mount them on every boot. Also take care of UIDs, GIDs, modes and SELinux labels. See this answer to get started: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526. And please don't say that's a different question. Basic concepts are the same.

Comment: @IrfanLatif How many methods are there in what you posted above? And is it better than doing it the Link2SD way?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56744757#56744757

Answer (score 0):

You can not move all apps to SD card. You can install some app to SD card. Part of the app also install on internal memory.

You can use SD card as internal storage. You can add SD card and choose as internal storage not as portable storage.

Comment: Be aware that formatting as internal storage means that you should never ever remove the sd-card from the phone. Also if the phone is reset or defect the data on the sd-card is lost as it can not be accessed anymore!