# Cannot move apps to SD card using App2SD

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, app2sd, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

I have Samsung Galaxy Core Prime running Android 5 Lollipop. I try to move some apps in the SD card with App2SD, but the file manager does not work.

Can anyone here tell me more about my issue? Because my mobile version is updated.

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] and explain more on "the file manager does not work"? What really happened? Did it not open? Or did it crash? Or..?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for replay me.I download an app with apkpure etc.after installation I try to move that app into sdcard.the option is hide to move into sdcard.mean to say that the app install in internal memory.just like playstore installed. I try to move those app with apps2sd .but the move options buttons not appear

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.sdcardmovable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move apps from internal to external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200850/how-to-move-apps-from-internal-to-external-storage)

Comment: No this is not answer of my question.